# I want to split the URL as mentioned in the description using python

Tags: python, split

```
URL = ftp://0.0.0.0/Engineering/Camera_Services/xxxxxx.x/QA_Release/zzzzzz_11-MAR-2022.zip
```

I want to split and add them to a variable like below

Expecting:

```
Custom Folder = Engineering/Camera_Services/xxxxxx.x/QA_Release
Filename = zzzzzz_11-MAR-2022.zip
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What doesn't work the way you expect it to work?

Comment: Just click the link: any browser worth its salt will download the file form such a link.

Comment: Actually i am trying to download a file from FTP . I have written python code to download. But in order to download it. I have to provide the input of the Custom folder & File name to download it. that code is working Fine. whereas i am planning to get a input from the user of the ftp link. FTP link wil contain multiple paths.. So i want to split the Custom folder name & File name seperately from the given input and feed it to the variable

Comment: Don't give the problem description: if that's your actual problem, that is the question you should ask. It it also good to provide some code with what you've already tried, instead of asking a more generic open question.

Comment: import ftplib

def getFile(ftp, filename):

    try:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
    except:
        print("Error retrieving the file")


ftp = ftplib.FTP("x.x.x.x")
try:
    ftp.login("userid", "password")
except:
    print("Verify the internet connection")
    exit()

Directory = input("Enter the Directory")
# ftp.cwd('Engineering/Camera_Services/xxxxxx/QA_Release')
ftp.cwd(Directory)
ftp.dir()
filename = input("Enter the Filename")

getFile(ftp, filename)

print("Downloaded successfully")
ftp.quit()

Answer (score 0):

```
URL = 'ftp://0.0.0.0/Engineering/Camera_Services/xxxxxx.x/QA_Release/zzzzzz_11-MAR-2022.zip'

Filename = URL.split("/")[-1]
Custom_Folder = "/".join(URL.split("/")[3:-1])
```